# Aligning bootstrap carousel controls middle vertical

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am using a Bootstrap carousel and I would like to vertically center the chevron arrows I am using to slide back and forward in the carousel. Currently they are horizontally centered, but aligned to the top.

Code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide">

      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Carousel items -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="item active">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="text-center">
              <h1>Header</h1>
              <p>Content</p>
            </div>
          </div><!--.row-->
        </div><!--.item-->
      </div>
      <a data-slide="prev" data-target="#Carousel" href="javascript:;" class="left carousel-control"><i
        class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <a data-slide="next" data-target="#Carousel" href="javascript:;" class="right carousel-control"><i
        class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div><!--.Carousel-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this CSS to center them vertically and align `20px` from left and right of your carousel.

```
.carousel .left > i,
.carousel .right > i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.carousel .right > i {
  left: auto;
  right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I split left and right and assigned 20px left and right respectively.

Comment: Yes, just edited. And it should be `.right` instead of `.next`.

Comment: why  this transform: translateY(-50%);?

Comment: To move up the arrows by half of their height. This is because `top: 50%` won't center the buttons exactly.